# iOS 7 Notification center not called

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

i have use this code for doing playing some videos. and want to recieve event when finish the play.
but not get the event using Notification center.

i have tried this code

```
    NSString * str=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"iGreet" ofType:@"m4v"];

    NSURL * url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:str];

    MPMoviePlayerController * movieController=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
    movieController.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
    [movieController.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];

    [movieController setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];
    movieController.shouldAutoplay=YES;

    [self.view addSubview:movieController.view];
    [movieController setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
    [movieController play];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(onStop:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:movieController];

}

  -(void)onStop:(NSNotification*)notification
{


}
```

Comment: If you are passing object then your method should have  parameter. Change selector to  `onStop:`

Comment: check my update but still not working for me...onStop methos not being called...

Comment: You can look at this example and see how they do: [example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: Try with by calling `prepareToPlay` method and also register every MPMoviePlayerController  notification and see those are getting called or not? If not then try to take MPMoviePlayerController object as an instance variable not locally.

Comment: get the solution i ma declare my object in .h file....

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(onStop:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:movieController];
```

and

```
-(void)onStop:(NSNotification*)notification
{


}
```

It works for me.

Comment: really? In my project, it's called normally.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the documentation for MPMoviePlayerController

> This notification is not sent when a movie is displaying in fullscreen
>   mode and the user taps Done. The Done button pauses playback and
>   causes the movie player to exit fullscreen mode. To detect this
>   scenario, register for other notifications such as
>   MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification.

Perhaps that might help you